# React Native ProgressBarAndroid setState not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs

I'm having trouble figuring out the problem with the following code. I'm trying to change the prop animating on a ProgressBarAndroid, and make it toggle every second. The code works as intended if I set loading to true in my constructor, but not if it's set to false (which is what I want, I don't want it to start animating right away). When it's set to false, the progressbar stays invisible all the time. Any ideas?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ProgressBarAndroid } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {loading: false}; // works if it is set to true here instead

    // Toggle the state every second
    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({loading: !this.state.loading});
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <ProgressBarAndroid animating={this.state.loading}></ProgressBarAndroid>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue I had with `ProgressBarAndroid` a few weeks back. Once initiated as `false`, I was never able to set it back true.

The quick and dirty solution I had at the time was to just to move the state change outside of the `animating` prop.

In your case, changing this:

```
<ProgressBarAndroid animating={this.state.loading}></ProgressBarAndroid>
```

to this:

```
<View>
  { this.state.loading ? <ProgressBarAndroid/> : null }
</View>
```

and make sure to also include `View` from `react-native`.

Comment: Yeah this works, although it does mess with the positions of other components a bit. Another dirty workaround I just found, which doesn't affect the position of other components, is to first set loading to true, but then by using a setTimeout with a delay of 1 ms immediately set it back to false.

Comment: @user2227486 That method works as well, it was actually my initial solution, but you'd have to continuously increase the delay based on how many moving parts are happening synchronously...and while I didn't have position issues you can control the position issue by styling View.

Comment: @user2227486 You do not need that 1ms timeout. Just put that into `componentDidMount()` because that will be called after the initial render.